# Why Do We Need The Requirement of "Ordered by Inclusion" in this Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

My functional analysis textbook provides the following theorem:

"The union of a collection of subspaces totally ordered by inclusion is a subspace."

Why do we need the requirement of "totally ordered by inclusion" for this theorem to hold?

Comment: Look at the $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have enough background to understand your hint...

Comment: To be a subspace we have to be able to add elements of the union and remain within the union. If we have the total inclusion condition, we can show that there is a subspace containing both elements, and therefore containing their sum. The sum is therefore in the union. Lord Shark's hint gives two subspaces - and you will find if you check that the sum of an element from each is in one of the subspaces only if one of the elements is zero, The smallest subspace containing the two lines is the whole plane, the union is just the two co-ordinate axes.

Comment: Always try these things out on an example. Can you think of a concrete example of a collection of subspaces which isn't totally ordered by inclusion? Is the union of that collection a subspace?

Comment: Does it mean that the union of the collection of subspaces "totally ordered by inclusion" is just the biggest subspace - the one that contains all other subspaces - in the collection?

Comment: @Geophysics, it may well be the case thatthere is no "biggest subspace" in the collection.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I find this rather unintuitive because the subspaces are totally ordered by inclusion, which means there should be one subspace that contains all of the others. Could you explain to me what I am missing here?

Comment: No, that the subspaces are totally ordered means simply that every time you pick two of them, one of them contains the other, and certainly that does not mean that there is one of them which contains all the others… For example, the elements of $\mathbb N$ are totally ordered by the usual order $\leq$: if you pick two natural numbers, one of them is larger that the other, but certainly there is no element in $\mathbb N$ which is larger than all other numbers.

Comment: You can turn that into an example with subspaces. In the space $\mathbb R^\infty$ of all sequences of real numbers, consider for each $n\in\mathbb N$ the subspace $S_n$ of all sequences of $\mathbb R^\infty$ whose components after the $n$th are all zero. Then the family $\{S_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a totally ordered family of subspaces of $\mathbb R^\infty$ which does not have a member which contains all the rest.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't quite understand your first example. In your example of the elements of $\mathbb N$ being the naturals numbers, they are not subspaces because they are not closed under addition. Am I being wrong here?

Comment: Well, it was not an example of subspaces… you can ignore it if you prefer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez In your second example, when saying the family of $\mathrm S_n's$ being totally ordered, are you defining order as by inclusion?

Comment: Of course. ${}{}$

Comment: @MarkBennet In your first comment, didn't you mean the **largest** subspace containing the two lines is the whole plane, instead of the smallest? Also, when saying "the union is just the two co-ordinate axes", which union are you talking about?

Comment: @Geophysics A subspace is closed under addition, and under addition you get at least the plane (the plane can be part of a larger subspace depending on context). The union is simply the union as sets, so the points contained in he two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a collection of two subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ which is *not* totally ordered. Is the union a subspace?

Comment: And by "consider" I mean find an example and actually look at it!

Comment: Could you provide a formal proof of the theorem that makes use of this theorem? Or could you give me a link to the proof? Thank you.

Comment: I **really** suggest you try toprove it yourself. It is not difficult at all, just a matter of using the definitions.